# Issue with Parse & Facebook - do not recognize application

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I started to make a new app using Parse and Facebook.
In the Parse guide I need to put this function([This is the link to the guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users)) in the `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance.application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}
```

but when I do it I get an error:

```
'() -> FBSDKApplicationDelegate!' does not have a member named 'application'
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the parentheses for the `sharedInstance`. It should be `sharedInstance()`

Comment: Solved! How did you know it?

Comment: When I look at the Obj-C documentation, then it's written `[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance]`, which means that it is calling a class method. The Swift equivalent is `FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()`, otherwise you would simply be accessing a property